# Dynamically updating in d3 works for circles but not external SVGs

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Suppose I want to dynamically update the position and number of circles on a page using d3. I can do this, using the .data(), .enter(), .exit() pattern. Here is a working example.
http://jsfiddle.net/csaid/MFBye/6/

```
function updatePositions(data) {

  var circles = svg.selectAll("circle").data(data);

  circles.enter().append("circle");

  circles.exit().remove();

  circles.attr("r", 6)
      .attr("cx", 50)
      .attr("cy", function (d) {
      return 20 * d
  });

}
```

However, when I try to do the same thing with external SVGs instead of circles, many of the new data points after the first update do not appear on the page. Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/csaid/bmdQz/8/

```
function updatePositions(data) {

    var gs = svg.selectAll("g")
        .data(data);

    gs.enter().append("g");

    gs.exit().remove();

    gs.attr("transform", function (d, i) {
        return "translate(50," + d * 20 + ")";
    })

        .each(function (d, i) {
        var car = this.appendChild(importedNode.cloneNode(true));
        d3.select(car).select("path")
    });
}
```

I suspect this has something to do with the .each() used to append the external SVG objects, but I am at a loss for how to get around this. Also, the "cx" and "cy" attributes are specific for circles, and so I can't think how they could be used for external SVGs.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your code. The first problem, and reason why you're not seeing all the data points, is that your external SVGs contain `g` elements, which you are selecting. What this means is that after you first appended the elements, any subsequent `.selectAll("g")` selections will contain elements from those external SVGs. This in turn means that the data you pass to `.data()` gets matched to those and hence your selections do not contain what you expect. This is easily fixed by adding a class to the `g` elements you add explicitly and selecting accordingly.

The second problem is that you're executing the code that appends the external SVGs as part of the update selection. This means that those elements get added multiple times -- not something you would notice (as they overlap), but not desirable either. This is easily fixed by moving the call to clone the nodes to the `.enter()` selection.

Complete jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bmdQz/9/). As for your question about `cx` and `cy`, you don't really need them. You can set the position of any elements you append using the `transform` attribute, as you are doing already in your code.